# Latex Beamer Error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Tags: latex, beamer

Im working on presentation in Latex on overleaf. I found a nice looking template and started using ist. I was using columns and resizeboxes when this error occurred "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

I do get similar errors when i use columns in combination with tables.

The smallest code where i could reproduce the error is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{CNU}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Framename}
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
a & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
b & 4 & 5 & 6                   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
} % close resizebox
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The style file CNU.sty is

```
\mode<presentation>

\newif\ifbeamer@secheader
\beamer@secheaderfalse

%\DeclareOptionBeamer{secheader}{\beamer@secheadertrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\useoutertheme[footline=authorinstitutetitle,subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\makeatletter % [add curpage/total page at the bottom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100838/beamer-dresden-theme-miniframes-appeareance-and-frame-number-insertion)
\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}

\setbeamertemplate{title page} {
  \vbox{
    \vskip1.2em%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.5em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0.5em%\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.2em%\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \vskip0.5em%\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline} {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\useinnertheme{circles}

%\useoutertheme{default}
%\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{lem}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{thm}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{define}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\definecolor{CNU}{HTML}{3434b4}
\xdefinecolor{greywhite}{rgb}{0.914,0.914,0.953}   %RGB 233 233 243
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=CNU}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=CNU,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=CNU}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamercolor{uppercol}{bg=white}%
\setbeamercolor{lowercol}{bg=white}%
\newcommand{\boldtitle}{\xiaosi\heiti\textcolor{CNU}}

\newenvironment{textbox}[1]{
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol]{\boldtitle{#1}}
}
{\end{beamerboxesrounded}}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

%% try
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=CNU,fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{bg=CNU,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block body example}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{fine separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
%\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=CNU}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=CNU}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}
% \AtBeginSection[]{
%   \begin{frame}
%       \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
%   \end{frame}
% }

\mode
<all>
```

I cant find the error. Someone may help me?

Ive tried to edit the stylefile and looked through some other questions on stackoverflow but couldnt find a solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `table` environment inside of a `\resizebox`. In fact, don't use a `\resizebox` at all for elements which contain text (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for details). You will get a better result if you choose a suitable font size instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{CNU}

\usepackage{lmodern} % scaleable font

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Framename}
%\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{table}
\fontsize{92}{100}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
a & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
b & 4 & 5 & 6                   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%} % close resizebox
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]